# Load a web page inside a container - Polymer

Tags: polymer

Suppose I have this web page [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/)

Using polymer, is there an element to load a separate website inside a container?
Basically, my idea is to use a `paper-dialog` and show a separate web page inside it.
Or should I use plain HTML5 to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the way you'd do this is with an `<iframe>` tag, which is part of HTML since 4.0 Transitional (and was in Internet Explorer way back in 1997). I'd recommend it over the `<object>` approach because it was specifically for this purpose and has script sandboxing, which is essential if you don't trust the page you're hosting.

In your case it could be as simple as:

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com/html"></iframe>
```

Comment: Yeah! Did the same later on. Works fine now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So, as of now I did it using HTML

```
<div>
   <object type="text/html" data="http://www.w3schools.com/html/" width="800px" height="600px" style="overflow:auto;border:5px ridge blue">
   </object>
</div>
```